# How to parse string and get the specific part of string QT

Tags: c++, qt

this is my first project in `Qt`

I have project in `Qt` and I have a string look like this

```
"0044RQ039PR006000000AM009123456789CU003364PD0011"
```

how can I get the number after `AM` like this

```
QString firstThreeNumbers = "009"     //first 3 number's

QString restOfNumbers = "123456789"   //rest of number's
```

> the position of the `AM` is dynamic, it's maybe  look like this

```
"AM0091234567890044RQ039PR006000000CU003364PD0011"
```

Comment: No real time to make an answer, but check out the QRegExp class, especially the CapturedTexts method.  You could make a regular expression to collect both your number sections as CapturedTexts

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like the following will work

```
QString str = "0044RQ039PR006000000AM009123456789CU003364PD0011";

int index = str.IndexOf("AM");
if (index >= 0)
{
    QString number;
    index += 2;
    while (index < str.size() && str[index].isDigit())
    {
        number += str[index];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a regex?

```
(AM)([0-9]{3})([0-9]*)
```

The first group is your `AM`, then 3 mandatory digits, then the rest of your digits. You'd have 3 important groups + the full match.

You can play around with it [here](https://regex101.com/r/dYRGV5/1)

seems like it can be used with `QString`